# How to save images in a new folder (associated with my app) in gallery?

Tags: android, kotlin

I can insert the images in gallery by the following code -

```
val cr = contentResolver
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, mBitmap, "Pro-Draw Image" , "An image made by Pro-Draw app")
```

But I want the images to be inserted in gallery in a new folder associated with my app(like instagram and whatsapp). How to do that?

Please tell the changes to be done in the following code to achieve that -

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Any?): String {

        var result = ""

        if(mBitmap != null){

            try{
                val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes)// ye bitmap ko compress krega bytes ki help se aur un bytes ko hm
                // fos main write kr rhe hain

                val f = File(externalCacheDir!!.absoluteFile.toString() +
                        File.separator
                        + "Pro-Draw_"
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 // this is to have a different name of every file because it will change every millisecond
                        + ".png")


                val cr = contentResolver
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, mBitmap, "Pro-Draw Image" , "An image made by Pro-Draw app")

                val fos = FileOutputStream(f)
                fos.write(bytes.toByteArray())
                fos.close()

                result = f.absolutePath //here the path of file is there which will be used to share the file in MediaScanner

            }catch (e : Exception){

                result = ""
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**Please Help**

Comment: Dont use .insertImage() but .insert(). Then you have the control you want using ContentValues and RELATIVE_PATH (Android 10+). The insert() returns an uri. You can open an output stream for that uri and compress your bitmap to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here use this type of method

```
public void Save() {

        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/CustomCropTest");
        dir.mkdirs();

        File dest = new File(dir, filename);

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        refreshGallery(dest);

    }
    private void refreshGallery(File file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

If don't understand just comment I will try to explain you again ☺️

Comment: Here customcroptest as folder name which will contain your images

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I can't understand how to implement in the code that I have added in my question. Could you please tell ?